NT Local Service multiple failed login
I'm having this excessive failed login on the NT Local Service account.
Per checking, this is related to openssh ldap authentication.
Hoping you could provide some guidance on how to address this excessive login error.
Thank you



You should check the SFTP server's log - possibly that is a hacking attempt.

The first thing to understand is that is a user failing to logon.
